# IS there anyway with which MACOS process permission levels can be set?

Tags: macos, security, process

How do Apple maintains security levels of process on MAC OS?

Windows have low, medium, high integrity levels for process, how do we maintain process level security on MAC OS?

Comment: Since the advent of macOS, a lot of things have changed, security-wise. See here for more information on how SIP (System Integrity Protection) works: https://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/. Basically, process permission levels are determined by the system itself, for its own protection, more than anything else. You can elevate your own rights as a user to perform certain tasks (install/uninstall system-wide non-Apple apps, empty system caches, etc...), but little else. See also here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204899